# Getting a "The process failed to start (invalid command?). (1)" error when starting up Pyzo

Tags: python, pyzo

I recently booted up my Pyzo IDE with the intention of doing some programming, however, upon starting up the python shell it gave this following error:

> The given path was not found
>
> The process failed to start (invalid command?). (1)

I am not able to run any code with this error. If I try to run it nothing happens and the error re-appears.

I have tried reinstalling the whole thing without success, I have tried reading the log but there was no error message and I have also tried looking for posts regarding the same problem without success. I was hoping if someone could explain what my problem is and a possible solution, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

This is how I fixed it:

1. I went to `miniconda3` file in `C:\Users\<user>\Miniconda3` (might be in other file/the thing is you need to find the `miniconda3` file)
2. Find the Python application
3. Rename it  to "python.exe"
4. Then go to shell configuration and replace the path to the operable python program in "exe" with your path (for me it was 
   `C:\Users\<user>\Miniconda3\python.exe`)

Answer (score 0):

For me the solution was much simpler than the solution proposed.

I had misspelled the path to `python.exe`

1. Go to **Shell** tab
2. Press the button that says **Python** and has a small arrow at the right bottom
3. After pressing the button a drop-menu will appear. In this meanu choose **Edit shell configurations ...**

[image]

4. A new window will open. In this window put the correct path in the **exe** field

[image]

The path for me (windows 7) was `c:\users\user\appdata\local\programs\python\python38\python.exe`. For other users might be different